# How to log with winston with multiple users in the server

Tags: node.js, logging, jwt, winston

I am using winston for logging in my Node application. Every user gets authorized by the server on logging in and a `userId` is assigned to the user. I want to have userId specific logs but **without** having to mention in logging statement explicitly like so:

```js
winston.info("User " + userId + " is authorized");
```

Currently in my code I'm storing `userId` in `defaultMeta` of winston while authorization:

```
winston.defaultMeta = {userId: userId};
```

But when multiple users will be logged in simultaneously in the server then I won't be getting user specific logs with userId. I'm using jwt for authorization and authentication.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/tree/36586d3d30dfe32f9dd4fbabbd585e82d47d460d#filtering-info-objects

Comment: How would filtering info help exactly? Could you please explain @weirdpanda? I need userId to be printed with logs for all users.